# Persisting Simple Domain Entity with Collection of Ids Using EF

Tags: entity-framework

On my own projects I use RavenDB.  At work I use SQL Server and Entity Framework (code first).

So designing domain entities is a challenge, as I really enjoy RavenDB's ability to create an application-centric, DDD style application, that isn't tied at all to a database implementation.

At the moment I'm trying to persist an entity that has a collection of GUIDs that reference other entities in the system.  For example (not the actual class, but the same concept):

```
public class Thing
{
    public Thing()
    {
        this.VisibleSectionIds = new Collection<Guid>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Guid> VisibleSectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

Using RavenDB, I can persist this in a few lines of code with no need to redesign the database.  I can even make my collection of ids read-only.

Can people suggest ways that I could do a similar thing in EF without introducing mapping properties to other entities (this would break my DDD approach and possibly introduce N+1 issues).  Can I use EF to convert my collection of GUIDs to a text datatype in the database and convert it back again?